# How to use camera.near and camera.far to render a slice of 3d object

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, orthographic

zMin and zMax are the minimum and maximum z value of all the vertices. I have placedmy camera at (0,0,5) and facing towards origin. Each slice thickness is given by voxelDepth which is mostly 0.5 or 0.8. What I'm trying to do is render a slice of object at a time and read pixel values. But the loop to go from one slice to another is not working. Here is my loop.

```
for (var i = zMax ; i > zMin; i = i - voxelDepth){
        if(i>0){
            camera.near = i;
            camera.far = i - voxelDepth;
        }else{
            camera.near = i;
            camera.far = i + voxelDepth;
        }

        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        calculateVoxel();
}
```